# Disable enter to send on Twitter

Tags: twitter

From [Twitter Support](https://twitter.com/Support/status/):

> Sending a Direct Message on https://twitter.com  is fast and fluid. Press `enter` to send a message; `shift + enter` to start a new line.

Is it possible to disable the `enter` to send?

Comment: Unlikely. Facebook, for instance, turned on this "Feature", but allows you to disable it in your account settings. You may want to check Twitter settings to see if you can disable it there.